# Fast Data Warehouse for Application

Tags: python, multithreading, performance, google-bigquery

We are building an app that lets a user query data from a datawarehouse.
The data consists of strings and embeddings (in this case 768 dimensional vectors).
We use Python for coding this.

For this we currently use BigQuery. However as our tables get bigger (> 200k rows) the loading time is sometimes > 10 seconds. We need to reduce this.

I now see 2 options:

- Split data in multiple tables and use some kind of threading logic in python.
- Use a different data warehouse that is faster then bigquery.

What should we do if money is not a problem?
If threading is the answer how should we code this?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, you need to move your data to CloudSQL, and your application reads data from it.

Please refer [here](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/your-google-cloud-database-options-explained) for more information about how to choose the best tool for each use case

BigQuery is not suitable for this scenario. It is not designed to deliver milliseconds response for multiple concurrent jobs.

Comment: Why would you not reccommend alloydb?

Comment: https://www.toptal.com/database/google-bigquery-tutorial#:~:text=BigQuery%20is%20a%20REST%2Dbased,about%20a%20minute%20to%20complete.

this article discusses how bigquery is best for bigger datasets..

Comment: If you want to use BigQuery as an alternative to the Database in the application layer, then you need to do all the aggregation in advance... follow the article you shared: "BigQuery doesn’t like joins, so you should merge your data into one table to get better execution time. "